# Java find image on screen

Tags: java, image-processing

Can you guys give me hints on how to find a image on screen. I mean, a simple pixel combination. For exmaple, it finds coordinates of 30x30 pixel white square.

Java robot class allows me to find color of certain pixel. But i need to opposite, I want my program to scan my screen and then tell me the coords of this little image. Well I could go through all pixels with Robot, but it should be faster than that. Much faster.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Well I could go through all pixels with Robot, but it should be faster than that. Much faster.

I'm afraid that that's precisely what you'll have to do.

If all pixels should be white, you could first take 30 pixel wide steps and if you find a white pixel, take say, 5 pixel steps, and then if these pixels are white too, examine the remaining pixels in the square.

Something like this:

```
.        .        .        .        .        .



.        ..........        .        .        .
         ...... 
         .  .  .  .

         .  .  .  .
.        .        .        ..........        .
                           ..........
                           ..........
                           ..........
                           ..........
.        .        .        ..........
```

Comment: but what would how fast would it be? id like to use it to get a good score in a game..but going through all those..doesn't it proccess it forever?

Comment: Try it out. I did it for a tetris bot once... it worked fine (even though scanning a tetris field seems slightly easier than your situation).

Comment: Depends how clever you can be about it. There may be ways to do things like a form of binary search, or there could be various shortcuts you could take. For instance, you want to find a 30x30 pixel white square, which means that if the current pixel isn't white, you can safely skip 30 pixels without risking missing the square. It all depends on what you expect to be onscreen.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there's a much simpliler or more reliable solution to this. You can implement the [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) libraries inside your Java application to spot image elements on your screen and interact with them. It was meant to automate UI testing, but I think it can accommodate your needs pretty easily.

Sample application ([source](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/)):

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.sikuli.api.*;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.Mouse;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopMouse;
import org.sikuli.api.visual.Canvas;
import org.sikuli.api.visual.DesktopCanvas;

import static org.sikuli.api.API.*;

public class HelloWorldExample {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

           // Open the main page of Google Code in the default web browser
           browse(new URL("http://code.google.com"));

           // Create a screen region object that corresponds to the default monitor in full screen 
           ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();

           // Specify an image as the target to find on the screen
           URL imageURL = new URL("http://code.google.com/images/code_logo.gif");                
           Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(imageURL);

           // Wait for the target to become visible on the screen for at most 5 seconds
           // Once the target is visible, it returns a screen region object corresponding
           // to the region occupied by this target
           ScreenRegion r = s.wait(imageTarget,5000);

           // Display "Hello World" next to the found target for 3 seconds
           Canvas canvas = new DesktopCanvas();
           canvas.addLabel(r, "Hello World").display(3);

           // Click the center of the found target
           Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();
           mouse.click(r.getCenter());
     }
}
```

Also see [How to use Sikuli inside your Java programs](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html) for setup.

Comment: I'm little confused. You're using classes that I find in sikuli-standalone.jar which I downloaded from code.google's site, and that have documentation on code.google.... But link you posted seems to refer to another sikuli which has different set of classes. I downloaded both libraries. The one you use works OK, but it's hard to find HOWTOs. The other one has better documentation (you posted link to it), but it does not work at all. I'm really confused, is there two types of sikuli, or what? Thank you.

Comment: I can't quite remember, but I think I only shared the link at the bottom for the purposes of installing/setting up Sikuli for use in your Java projects. It's probably only relevant until around step 5, I wouldn't follow the sample code demonstrated in there. You should probably be following the documentation on code.google. What exactly isn't working? To be honest, I haven't tried using Sikuli with Java directly, only with JRuby. But if it works for JRuby I don't see why it shouldn't work with Java.

Comment: sikuli-standalone**.jar works fine for me (the one I downloaded from code.google), and I also find pretty good examples on how to use it's classes. So everything is fine now. I was just curious if there are two types of sikuli.