# Find image within image in java

Tags: java, image, search, video

I've been looking forever and I cant find anything that works so I'm going to ask,
Basically I'm trying to have java look through a video and find a certain image, like a logo or something but for now I'm just working on the find image in other image part before the video. I'm using eclipse and code from this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824314/java-find-image-on-screen),
 But I cant get it to work and always get the error:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.sikuli.api.visual.Canvas.addLabel(Canvas.java:230)    at
>   Search.main(Search.java:39)

Heres my code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.sikuli.api.*;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.Mouse;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopMouse;
import org.sikuli.api.visual.Canvas;
import org.sikuli.api.visual.DesktopCanvas;

import static org.sikuli.api.API.*;

public class Search {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

            // Open the main page of Google Code in the default web browser
            browse(newURL("http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/File:Wii_U_(logo).png"));
            // Create a screen region object that corresponds to the default monitor in full screen 
            ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();

            // Specify an image as the target to find on the screen
            URL imageURL = new URL("http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/zelda/images/1/17/Wii_U_%28logo%29.png/revision/latest?cb=20110609012932");                
            Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(imageURL);

            // Wait for the target to become visible on the screen for at most 5 seconds
            // Once the target is visible, it returns a screen region object corresponding
            // to the region occupied by this target
            ScreenRegion r = s.wait(imageTarget,5000);

            // Display "Hello World" next to the found target for 3 seconds
            Canvas canvas = new DesktopCanvas();
            canvas.addLabel(r, "Hello World").display(3);

            // Click the center of the found target
            Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();
            mouse.click(r.getCenter());
    }
```

}